# javascript to replace a substring with value of how many times it is repeated

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I had little bit difficulty in giving proper title to this question. Below is an example of what i want.

```
var originalString ="hello all, This is a hello string written by hello";
var substringToBeCounted = "hello";
var expectedString ="1 hello all, This is a 2 hello  string written by 3 hello; .
```

I am tyring to append the count of instance of "hello" in the whole string.

This is the working solution i got so far:

```
   var hitCount = 1;
        var magicString = "ThisStringWillNeverBePresentInOriginalString";
        while(originalString .match(substringToBeCounted ).length >0){

                            originalString = originalString .replace(substringToBeCounted , hitCount + magicString  );
                            hitCount++;
                    }

    var re = new RegExp(magicString,'gi');

    originalString = originalString.replace(re, subStringToBeCounted);
```

To explain the above code: i am looping until match finds the "hello" in original string and in loop I am changing hello to some weird string with the count i want.

In the end I am replacing the weird string back to hello.

This solution looks very hacky for me.

Is there any clever solution to address this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace accepts a function as the replacement; that way you can return what you want to

```
var originalString = "hello all, This is a hello string written by hello";
var substringToBeCounted = "hello";

var count = 0;
var reg = new RegExp(substringToBeCounted, 'g');
// this could have just been /hello/g if it isn't dynamically created

var replacement = originalString.replace(reg, function(found) {
  // hint: second function parameter is the found index/position
  count++;
  return count + ' ' + found;
});
```

To make this a bit more reusable:

```
function counterThingy(haystack, needle) {
  var count = 0;
  var reg = new RegExp(needle, 'g');

  return haystack.replace(reg, function(found) {
    count++;
    return count + ' ' + found;
  });
}

var whatever = counterThingy(originalString, substringToBeCounted);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace